# Differential Pairs and GND

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, signal, differential

I have some doubts about different configurations of differential pair I have seen in many cases:

[image]

In these schemes, biasing network for the gate is not shown for simplicity. All of them are excited by an input differential signal, but

- In 1) two different opposite signal sources are applied to the transistors. The output is taken between the drain of one MOSFET and GND. It is clear for me.
- In 2) the pair receives a differential signal in a different way, by using only 1 voltage source. I have the following doubt: how can that signal be amplified by the MOSFETS, if they are not referred to GND? How can that circuit work?
- 3) is like 1), but the output signal is taken from both drains and not from 1 drain and GND. This allows to double the gain. But, despite that difference, is there a reason to prefer 3) on 1) or viceversa? I'd say that 3) is better because noise on GND is not transmitted to the output signal. Is it true?
- 4) is like 2), but the output signal is taken from both drains. I have the same doubts said about 3) and 1).

**Other doubts**:

- I have seen that the current source is often replaced by a simple resistor. In this case, it is important for it to be very high in order not to have common mode gain. But, in general, which is the reason for choosing a current source between Source and GND, or an high resistor between Source and GND?
- Sometimes this kind of circuit works with VDD and -VDD, so with dual voltage supply. Which is the reason for choosing it or a single supply?

Comment: A whole bunch of interesting questions that are difficult to answer in a single comment... Most importantly, circuits 2 and 4 will not work. They can work if you connect resistors (with high resistances) between gates and ground (try to imagine where currents flow and what voltages are in this configuration). To figure out why a common current source is connected between the sources and ground, change simultaneously both input voltages (the so-called "common mode") and observe how the collector voltages change towards the ground. Try to explain what the impact of this is in both cases above...

Comment: Indeed, the biasing networks for the gates will solve the first problem (missing resistances between the gates and ground)...

Comment: But how can the Mosfet read the input signal, if it is not referred to GND?

Comment: @ Kinka-Byo, Very interesting question giving rise to interesting thoughts about the philosophy of differential pair biased by the side of sources. There is always a ground but it is the common point between the sources. At a differential mode it is really a "stiff" ground (constant voltage)... a kind of a virtual ground... but at a common-mode it is a "soft"... "movable" ground... i.e. there is not a ground:) And this is the clever trick in this configuration - there is a ground for the useful differential signal and there is no ground for the undesired common-mode signal... "dynamic ground".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this picture will help understanding Fig. 2 and Fig. 4...

[image: Floating input source]

... and this - the need of a bipolar supply:

[image: Bipolar dif amplifier]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In 1) the output is Voltage across resistor "R", so it is referenced to Vdd. Your schematic shows it referenced to ground, which is incorrect. If Vdd is constant, both will be the same AC output with a different DC offset. However if Vdd is variable or noisy, referencing the output to Vdd will reject most of the noise, whereas referencing the output to GND will reject none of it.

Schematics 2) and 4) cannot work in practice because, as you noticed, source Vm sets the differential input voltage, but nothing sets the common mode input voltage. So you can split the Vm source in two identical sources Vm/2 like in schematic 3, and connect the middle point between these sources to the common mode voltage. In schematics 1 and 3 the common mode voltage is GND but you can use any voltage as long as it within the range allowed by your FETs. Note in schematics 1 and 3, both sources have value Vm, so differential input voltage is 2x higher in schematics 1 and 3 than in the others.

> 3) is like 1), but the output signal is taken from both drains and not from 1 drain and GND. This allows to double the gain.

yes, 2x the gain.

> But, despite that difference, is there a reason to prefer 3) on 1) or viceversa? I'd say that 3) is better because noise on GND is not transmitted to the output signal. Is it true?

As said above in schematic 1 the output should be referenced to Vdd, not GND.

Schematic 3 provides a differential output, which is useful if you need a differential signal (also see below). Another option is to replace the resistors with a current mirror, which results in a push-pull current output.

> I have seen that the current source is often replaced by a simple resistor. In this case, it is important for it to be very high in order not to have common mode gain.

Schematic 1 would have common mode gain, but schematic 3 would not, because the output is differential. Variation in Ibias causes common mode output voltage variation, but not differential output voltage variation. However varying Ibias does change the differential gain.

> But, in general, which is the reason for choosing a current source between Source and GND, or an high resistor between Source and GND?

If you're considering an opamp input stage and the input common mode voltage spans almost the whole range between the supplies, if you want a reasonably constant current, there is no way to do it with a resistor. Also a current source will result in better common mode rejection and power supply noise rejection.

> Sometimes this kind of circuit works with VDD and -VDD, so with dual voltage supply. Which is the reason for choosing it or a single supply?

One supply is cheaper than 2 supplies if you can get away with it.

Comment: I have a note about "the output is Voltage on resistor 'R', so it is referenced to Vdd. Your schematic shows it referenced to ground, which is incorrect." Really, the voltage drop across R is the true voltage output of the stage. R acts as a current-to-voltage converter that converts the output collector current to output voltage and this voltage is tied to Vcc. But usually the input of the next stage is tied to ground; so we use the complementary voltage Vcc - VR as an output instead the original VR. We can use VR directly if the next stage is with the opposite P-channel transistors.

Comment: Indeed... but I've never seen a circuit where the next stage is referenced to GND, usually it's a VAS stage like [this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cmos+opamp+schematic&t=brave&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fm.eet.com%2Fmedia%2F1069696%2Ffig6.gif) or another diff pair, or a folded cascode, all referenced to positive supply...

Comment: Regarding the power supply, which is the advantage of choosing 2 supplies?

Comment: @Kinka-Byo With positive and negative supplies the circuit can process and output both positive and negative voltage, and reference is really 0V.

Comment: @ Kinka-Byo, When the lower end of the current source is connected to a negative power supply, the MOSFET sources can go down below zero so the gates are at zero input voltage. This means there is no need of some biasing from the side of gates since the transistors are biased from the side of sources. Only the gates should be somehow connected to ground - either through the input single-ended sources or through additional resistors (see the picture below).

Comment: @ peufeu, You are right about the connection between the differential stage and next stage. Designers alternate transistors: if the input stage is implemented with p-n-p, the next stage is implemented with n-p-n transistors and vice versa. Thus the output of each stage is alternatively referenced to the negative and positive rails.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to find and more expensive to get matched transistors for current sources if you're making a discrete circuit and a lot more space too. But none of these are issues on silicon. I think on silicon it actually saves space since you can use on reference transistor for many mirrors of different values by varying transistor geometry and because transistors are smaller and cheaper than resistors on silicon (I think).

If you're operating off a battery, single supply is a lot more convenient but it comes at a penalty in performance such as how close your output can get to GND, noise, bias currents, etc.